# Matching degree-based geographical coordinates with a regular expression

Tags: regex, perl, coordinates

I'd like to be able to identify patterns of the form

```
28°44'30"N., 33°12'36"E.
```

Here's what I have so far:

```
use utf8;
qr{
    (?:
    \d{1,3} \s*  °   \s*
    \d{1,2} \s*  '   \s*
    \d{1,2} \s*  "   \s*
    [ENSW]  \s* \.?
            \s*  ,?  \s*
    ){2}
}x;
```

Needless to say, this doesn't match. Does it have anything to do with the extended characters (namely the degree symbol)? Or am I just screwing this up big time?

I'd also appreciate directions to `CPAN`, if you know of something there that will solve my problem. I've looked at [Regex::Common](http://search.cpan.org/~abigail/Regexp-Common-2010010201/) and [Geo::Formatter](http://search.cpan.org/~kokogiko/Geo-Formatter-0.0.1/lib/Geo/Formatter.pm), but none of these do what I want. Any ideas?

**Update**

It turns out that I needed to take out `use utf8` when reading the coordinates from a file. If I manually initialize a variable with a coordinate, it would match fine, but as soon as I read that same line from a file, it wouldn't match. Taking out `use utf8` solved that. I guess I don't really understand what `utf8` is doing.

Comment: If you suspect the degree symbol, try replacing it with a `\D` and see if it matches then.

Comment: I'm sorry, it works for me...

$coord = '28°44\'30"N., 33°12\'36"E.'; @info = $coord =~ /($re)/; print @info;

How are you using your pattern?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try dropping the `use utf8` statement.

The degree symbol corresponds to character value 0xB0 in my current encoding (whatever that is, but it ain't UTF8). 0xB0 is a "continuation byte" in UTF8; it is expected to by the second, third, or fourth character of a sequence that begins with something between 0xC2 and 0xF4. Using that string with `utf8` will give you an error.

Comment: it doesn't, on my machine; in fact, it does not seem to make much of a difference. Would you know how I would go about including the damned `º` in the regex?

Comment: Pedro: And that is why you are supposed to [decode your strings properly](http://p3rl.org/UNI) before you work on them with character oriented operations such as regex. By merely dropping the `utf8` pragma, you have swept the symptoms of the problem under the carpet - but it still exists to unexpectedly bite you in the future. I bet that in your program the test string is not a literal as in Kinopiko's answer and `Devel::Peek` would reveal that the simplified example is not functionally equivalent to your real code from which it is derived - please post a *complete* code example the next time.

Comment: You're right, of course. My test strings were read in from a file.

Answer (score 5):

This:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use utf8;
my $re = qr{
    (?:
    \d{1,3} \s*  °   \s*
    \d{1,2} \s*  '   \s*
    \d{1,2} \s*  "   \s*
    [ENSW]  \s* \.?
            \s*  ,?  \s*
    ){2}
}x;
if (q{28°44'30"N., 33°12'36"E.} =~ $re) {
    print "match\n";
} else {
    print "no match\n";
}
```

works:

```
$ ./coord.pl 
match
```

Comment: And strangely, it matches even without `use utf8`. Your regex is exactly like mine, no? Or what I missing something? Weird; anyway, thanks!

Comment: It's not strange. If you don't use UTF-8 you get a bytewise match, but if you do use UTF-8 you get a character match. The problem you have is that you have not ensured about your input from the file.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot the `x` modifier on the `qr` operator.

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately, that was only a typo here. It still doesn't work :(

Answer (score 1):

The `?:` at the beginning of the regex makes it non-capturing, which is probably why the matches cannot be extracted or seen. Dropping it from the regex may be the solution.

If all of the coordinates are fixed-format, [`unpack`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/unpack.html) may be a better way of obtaining the desired values.

```
my @twoCoordinates = unpack 'A2xA2xA2xAx3A2xA2xA2xA', "28°44'30"N., 33°12'36"E.";

print "@twoCoordinates";  # returns '28 44 30 N 33 12 36 E'
```

If not, then modify the regex:

```
my @twoCoordinates = "28°44'30"N., 33°12'36"E." =~ /\w+/g;
```

Comment: yeah, but I've been simplifying the regex, including removing the non-capturing parentheses, to no avail.

thanks for the unpack idea though, it sounds like it should work, although I'm not sure that I won't see coordinates with 3 digit degrees, 1 digit minutes, etc.

Comment: The thing is, my priority is to actually identify strings of that nature. `unpack` would sure come in handy if I knew a particular string were a coordinate, but but if I knew that I wouldn't need `unpack` because I'd identified it via a regex. :(